# Migrating data from one database to another database in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to migrate related data but with different column names from one database to another database? and im talking about very large amount of data here. someone has an idea? I have tried exporting it to CSV and importing to the otherdatabase but i get errors saying:

```
invalid column count in CSV input in line 1
```

So if anyone has an efficient and effective way of doing this please share. 
Or if anyone can guide mo through this CSV mapping in excell on how to properly do it, i would really appreciate

Comment: i have tried exporting the whole table to a .csv and importing it to the other database. But i get errors sometimes.

Comment: EXPORT to csv and then `LOAD DATA INFILE your_file.csv INTO your_table`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Could you also specify what are the errors that you get and which program gives you those errors?

Comment: i have edited the post above including the error.

Comment: Are you talking about different databases inside the same MySQL process? Then you can just do an INSERT ... SELECT query, which would be a lot easier than exporting to files.

Comment: im talking about migrating 11 thousand data. How would you do an insert to that? and i dont get what you mean about "different databases inside the same MySQL process", but what im trying to migrate is from one mysql database (table) to another mysql database (table)

Comment: @BelmarkCaday Are both databases in the same server? Also, eleven thousand rows is not a lot, believe me (I've inserted *hundreds of thousands* rows with a single insert without a hickup... it may take a bit of time, but it works)

Answer (score 12):

There are two cases in this:

1. The databases are stored in the same server
2. The databases are stored in different servers

### Solution 1: Databases in the same server

You just need to insert the data in the destination table:

```
insert into dbDestination.tblDestination (field1, field2, ...)
select ...
from dbSource.tblSource
```

***Notes***

1. The `select` statement must include the fields you need to copy to the destination table.
2. The fields in the `select` statement must be in the same order as the fields specified in the field list in the `insert` portion

### Solution 2: Databases in different servers

I would export the data to a plain text file, and then import it. I personally prefer .csv files, but it's up to you.

You have two possibilities: To use `select... into outfile` or to use the system terminal (command window).

**a. Using `select... into outfile` and `load data`**

1. In the server where `dbSource` is:

   ```
   select ...
   from dbSource.tblSource
   into outfile [your destination file]
   ...
   ```
2. Copy the file to the destination server.
3. In the server where `dbDestination` is:

   load data local infile [your file]
   ...

***Notes***

1. The fields in the `select` statement must be in the same order as the fields specified in the field list in the `insert` portion
2. Check MySQL reference manual for the appropriate usage of `select... into outfile` and `load data...`

**b. Using the terminal**

1. In Linux (or other Unix systems), open a terminal window and enter the following command:

   ```
   $ mysql -h [sourceServer] -u [yourUser] -p[yourPassword] dbSource -e"select ..." | sed 's/\t/,/g' > yourDestinationFile.csv
   ```
2. Copy the file to the destination server
3. Start MySQL console, and use `load data ...``

***Notes***

1. The fields in the `select` statement must be in the same order as the fields specified in the field list in the `insert` portion
2. The `| sed 's/\t/,/g'` part converts the output of the mysql query to a .csv file. You can use another separator instead of `,`. For further reference about `sed` check http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-sed.html
3. The destination file **will have row headers**, so you will need to ignore them when you import the data. Simply add `ignore 1 lines` at the end of the `load data...` sentence.

---

To copy data from one database to another is a very simple task. Hope this points you in the right direction.

A word of advice: Download the reference manual for your MySQL version and keep it at hand. You can find most of your solutions there.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is with the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Database.Table(field 1, field 2,...)
SELECT * FROM Database2.Table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
INSERT INTO dbname.tablename(fields...);
SELECT * FROM olddatabase.oldtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware!!!

```
INSERT INTO dbname.tablename(fields...);
SELECT * FROM olddatabase.oldtable;
```

will only work if id's follow.

Select fields ommitting ID so that auto-increment can give a new ID to the imported rows.